# Permissions Xampp

Tags: permissions, xampp

Gents, I have a lot of problems getting Xampp to work. I installed Xampp with this [tutorial](https://vitux.com/how-to-install-xampp-on-your-ubuntu-18-04-lts-system/). After that I set the permissions following [this](https://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/linux-tutorials/xampp-htdocs-permission-issue-and-fix-in-ubuntu.html) tutorial.

Here is what I did:

1- download xampp-linux-x64-7.4.2-0-installer.run

```
chmod 755 xampp-linux-x64-7.4.2-0-installer.run
```

2- install the package

```
sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-7.4.2-0-installer.run
```

3- Run the graphical manager

4- Find the owner and the group

```
ls -ld /opt/lampp/htdocs 

whoami

id -gn
```

Change ownership to myself

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/lampp/htdocs

sudo chown -R jos:jos /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

This is as far as I got. All according to the tutorials, but now the problems begin.

When I want to install Joomla or WordPress this is not enough. The privileges 755 won't allow me to install either. I have to set them to 777. Even so, I have to manually remove the installation folder, and create the configuration file. In WP I have to change the wp-config.php to remove the ftp credentials pop up.

All this is a privileges issue. When I upload an Akeeba .jpa backup all files and folders are locked, and owned by daemon. When I install something it will be owned by the user daemon and group daemon.

httpd.conf in /opt/lampp/etc tells me the User and Group are daemon

```
User daemon
Group daemon
```

I stopped the server, changed that to jos and jos, and restarted. Now phpmyadmin throws an error. (So I changed it back to daemon daemon to get it working again.)

How do I solve this problem?

---

Continuing my quest, I know that the daemon controls a lot. I can't change it, but what I can do is add user jos to the group daemon and vice versa. That works. now I can install software and work with phpmyadmin.

I still have to chmod -R 777 on the folder everytime I install software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo chown -R daemon wordpress-folder

// or use htdocs folder
```

the xampp apache server uses a user named daemon to access the folders inside htdocs, this will fix all the permission problems.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I do is:

1. Open file wp-config.php in /opt/lampp/htdocs/your_wordpress/wp-config.php edit with text editor.
2. Add this comment in the last line of your wp-config.php

//** To add the direct installation of the themes **//

define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');

3. Save it and restart apache.
4. The last is "sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs"